# How to increase the size of a checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to increase the size of a checkbox in my Userform.

In the properties tab, I can change the height and the width of the object but it doesn't change the size of the square. I add a picture to explain my issue.

[image: Checkbox]

Thank you.

Comment: @teylyn Of course that the reason I post a message here. The only solution I found was relative to a CheckBox on the worksheets not in an userform.

Comment: Only way I know is to use a label with unicode character for check box, ☐ ☑ ☒ and then implement your own click event to mimic checking.  This way you can size the box by font size.

Comment: But when an user will click on it, the checkbox will not be checked right? Or there is a way to change the unicode character after a click event? @PortlandRunner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Portland Runner's comment is a good suggestion. For example, in the click event of the label (using WingDings 2) ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Label1_Click()

    If Label1.Caption = "Q" Then
       Label1.Caption = "R"
    Else
        Label1.Caption = "Q"
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This answer helps me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the VBA checkbox:

1. The size of the square
2. The size of the caption text

My solutions:

1. Create a frame in which you put the checkbox object. A frame has the property Zoom. Set that property at whatever value you want. Then change the font size of the button to match the rest of the fonts in the form. The frame doesn't have to have a title, and you can select an invisible border for it. In that way, the user doesn't see it.
2. For whatever reason, the checkbox's text looks smaller than the rest of the objects, even though it is the same font size. My solution for this was to remove the checkbox's text and add a standard label object to the right.